# Explanation of $z^{-1}$ and $T_{1,2}$ within E0 Bluetooth encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, lfsr, e0

I am trying to understand how E0 Bluetooth algorithm exactly works. I know that $y_t$ is the sum of $x_1$ to $x_4$ and can take values $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. Also $S_{t+1}$ = $(y_t + c_t)/2$ and can be $\{0,1,2,3\}$. But I don't understand what $z^{-1}$ and $T_{1,2}$ means.

[image: E]

According to the [Bluetooth core specification](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/15/Bluetooth/core_10_b.pdf):

> $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two different linear bijections over $GF(4)$.

Picture and explanation is on page 164.

Can you please clarify this and provide some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article  [Cryptanalysis of the Bluetooth Stream Cipher](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-22.pdf) by Canniere et al. explains in details;

\begin{align}
T_1 : \mathbb Z^2_2 &\mapsto \mathbb Z^2_2\\
(x_1, x_0) &\to (x_1, x_0)\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
T_2 : \mathbb  Z^2_2 &\mapsto \mathbb  Z^2_2\\
(x_1, x_0) &\to (x_1, x_1 \oplus x_0)\\
\end{align}

$Z^{-1}$ are 2-bit [digital delay lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_delay_line). $Z^{-1}$ is delay one sample and $Z^{-N}$ is delay by $N$ sample. This can be implemented by [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) in electronics and with arrays in software.

Why $T_1$ and $T_2$ are bijections? $T_1$ is bijection since it is just swapping the values. To prove that $T_2$ is a bijection; first, notice that it is surjective. To see it is an injective notice that we can find the inverse of every element on the range.

---

Extra:

To understand $\mathbb Z_2^2$ we need to construct it: We can also represent $\mathbb Z_2^2 $ as $\operatorname{GF}(2^2)$. It is the second-degree extension of $\operatorname{GF}(2)$ by the roots of the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$. Let $\alpha$ is one root then the second root is $\beta  = 1 + \alpha$.

By using $1 + 1 = 0$ and $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$ we can build the addition and multiplication tables.

Addition:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+  & 0&   1&   \alpha &  \beta  \\
\hline
    0&   0 &  1 &  \alpha &  \beta \\ 
1 &  1 &  0 &  \beta &  \alpha  \\
\alpha &  \alpha &  \beta &  0 &  1  \\
\beta &  \beta &  \alpha &  1 &  0  \end{array}
$$

Multiplication:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot &   0 &  1 &  \alpha &  \beta  \\
\hline
0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0  \\
1 &  0 &  1 &  \alpha &  \beta  \\
\alpha &  0 &  \alpha &  \beta &  1  \\
\beta &  0 &  \beta &  1 &  \alpha  
  \end{array}$$

Comment: Note: delays can be represented by array indexes.

Comment: To elaborate further, z^-n is standard notation in circuit diagrams for an element that delays by n clock cycles.  It's origin is the Z-transform used in digital signal processing.  I use it all the time, but it's not intuitive at all.

Comment: @Evariste thanks, under your guidance, I've added more into that part.